# Amortized Cost Analysis with a Stack

Tags: algorithm, amortized-analysis

Suppose I have a stack backed by an n-element array with cost 1 to push, cost 1 to take an element out of the array, and the cost of resizing the array is the number of elements moved.

1) Every time the stack becomes full, I copy over the current n elements into a new array that's one element larger than before.  My text claims that a series of n pushes will result in a total cost of:

1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n

Why is this?  Say my array starts off with n = 1.

I push and the stack is now full (cost 1)
I increment size of array (n = 2 and cost of 2)
I push and stack is now full (cost of 1)
I increment size of the array (n = 3 and cost of 4)
...

What am I missing?

2) Suppose I double the size of the array every time the stack is full.  Now I have a series of n pushes starting with a 1-element array:

I push and the stack is now full (cost of 1)
I double array size and copy 1 element over (cost of 2, n = 2)
I push and stack is now full (cost of 1)
I double array size and copy 2 elements over (cost of 4, n = 4)
...

Does this analysis look right?

For a series of n pushes, it would yield 1 + 2 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 8 + ... + 1 + 2 ^ (n/2)

Comment: regarding 1) I cannot follow your calculation of time-cost either (why does it cost 4 to increment the size of the array with 3 elements?);  regarding 2) no, why are you always resizing the array after just a single push operation? The backing-array is not full at that point

Comment: You're right re: 2).  It should be 1 for insert, 4 for resizing and inserting (1 for taking element out, 2 for resizing, 1 for putting element in), 1 for insert, 6 for resizing and inserting, 1 for insert, 1 for insert, 10 for resizing and inserting, etc...thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything sounds reasonable to me:

**1)** Let's start with an empty stack, represented by an array of initial size `n=1`

- push 1. element => `cost = <push-cost> = 1` => array now full
- push 2. element => `cost = <resize-cost> + <push-cost> = n + 1 = 2` => `n := n + 1 = 2`
- push 3. element => `cost = <resize-cost> + <push-cost> = n + 1 = 3` => `n := n + 1 = 3`

...and so on, which indeed results in total cost of `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` when pushing `n` elements.

**2)** You don't say what your text says about this behavior, but the calculation is similar:

- push 1. element => `cost = <push-cost> = 1` => array now full
- push 2. element => `cost = <resize-cost> + <push-cost> = n + 1 = 2` => `n := 2 * n = 2`
- push 3. element => `cost = <resize-cost> + <push-cost> = n + 1 = 3` => `n := 2 * n = 4`
- push 4. element => `cost = <push-cost> = 1` => array now full
- push 5. element => `cost = <resize-cost> + <push-cost> = n + 1 = 5` => `n := 2 * n = 8`
- push 6. element => `cost = <push-cost> = 1`
- push 7. element => `cost = <push-cost> = 1`
- push 8. element => `cost = <push-cost> = 1` => array now full
- push 9. element => `cost = <resize-cost> + <push-cost> = n + 1 = 9` => `n := 2 * n = 16`

...which results in total costs of

`1 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 5 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 9 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1...`

Note how resize operations always happen at an element `2^n+1`, followed by `2^n-1` "resize-free" operations. As a result, we can rewrite that as (collapse `+ 1`-chains to the left)

`1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ...`

which (informally) indicates total costs of `O(n)` or amortized costs of `O(1)` per push-operation.